# Await is not awaiting in JavaScript, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I am struggalling to understand the below case. This is my expactations here:

1. Once the getRegions() would be executed (there is an API call made there), then the data would be taken from the response.
2. The state would set as it is first awaited and then only set.
3. Console.log should log out `State is + the data` from the region.

   ```
    handleRegion = async (e) => {
      const { data } = getRegions(e.target.value)
        .then(function (done) {
          console.log("done");
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log("error");
        });
      await this.setState({ region: data });
      console.log("state is: " + this.state.region);
    };
   ```

Instead it first Executes the `State is: undefiened` and only then it is writting done.

Ideally I wanted the code to be written as:

```
  handleRegion = async (e) => {
    const { data } = await getRegions(e.target.value)         
    await this.setState({ region: data });
  };
```

The event is comming from a DDL list

```
 <select
                        className="form-control optiontpicker option-design"
                        name="area"
                        onChange={this.handleRegion}
                      >
```

So every time the DDL would be chaanged this function should beexecuted in this order.

Comment: In the first code block, the expression after your `await` is not a promise, so code execution is not awaiting the promise you created above that statement.

Comment: Which ones? The one from API call getRegions? The setState as far as I am aware returns a promise. How do I change the code? How do you see that it is not returning a Promise, still trying to grasp this topic.

Comment: You didn't `await` the call to `getRegions(...).then(...).catch(...);` So the returned object is a promise. There is no `data` property on a promise object, so it's `undefined`.

Comment: if I do this:   `const { data } = await getRegions(e.target.value)  ` it still doesn't work.

Comment: @RaitisLebedevs trincot is correct, nothing in the React documentation suggests that `this.setState()` returns a promise, so awaiting it will probably not wait for the state to update. The other thing is that your `.then()` callback doesn't have a return value so it will cause your `await` to yield `undefined` instead of the object you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things that you did wrong 1. you did not add `await` before `getRegions`.
and 2. You added `await` before `setState`.
Why those two things are wrong?
`SetState` is asynchronous but it does not return a promise. `Await` works only with promises.

```
handleRegion = async (e) => {
   const { data } = await getRegions(e.target.value)
       console.log("done");
   this.setState({ region: data },()=>{
        console.log("state is: " + this.state.region);
});
 
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is asynchronous but it is not `Promise` actually. So you cannot use `await` and `setState` together. You have to use `callback` instead, or promisify `setState` to use with `await`.

````
handleRegion = async (e) => {
   const { data } = await getRegions(e.target.value)         
   this.setState({ region: data }, () => {
     console.log("state is: " + this.state.region);
   });
 };```
````

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is asynchronous in nature, but it does not return a promise. Instead it calls your callback if you provide it as argument.

As you write that ideally you want to use `await` with it, you could *promisify* `setState` as follows:

```
promiseState = newState => 
    new Promise(resolve => this.setState(newState, resolve));
```

Then you can write the following code:

```
handleRegion = async (e) => {
    const { data } = await getRegions(e.target.value)         
    await promiseState({ region: data });
};
```